# multiple smilies for replies in guestbook

Tags: php, javascript, database, forms

I added smilies for replies on comments in a guestbook

It is working fine when I want to reply on 1 comment with this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET["action"] == "reply" ) {
    $commentrpl = substr(stripEmails(strip_tags($_POST["txtreply"])), 0, 250);

    $rpl_arr = array(
        "O:-)" => "<img src=\"".DOC_ROOT."images/sml/aa.gif\"\/>",
        ":-)"  => "<img src=\"".DOC_ROOT."images/sml/ab.gif\"\/>",
        ":-("  => "<img src=\"".DOC_ROOT."images/sml/ac.gif\"\/>",
    );

    $commentrpl  = strtr($commentrpl, $rpl_arr);
    $osDB->query('UPDATE ! SET reply = ? WHERE id = ?', array( 
        COMMENTS_TABLE, 
        $commentrpl, 
        $_REQUEST["commentid"] 
    ));
}
```

But as soon as there are more comments that needs a reply the smilies won't work anymore. (not clickable) What do I need to change so that for every reply I can use the smilies.

This is the piece of javascript that could be the problem too.

```
function smile4( txt ) {
    doInsert(" " + txt + " ", "", false, document.getElementById('txtreply'));
}
```

Form:

```
<form name="reply" method="post" action="showprofile.php?id={$profileid}&amp;commentid={$item.id}&amp;action=reply">
    <textarea id="txtreply" name="txtreply" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    <img src="images/sml/aa.gif" onclick="smile4('O:-)');" alt="O:-)">
    <input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="{lang mkey='send'}" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more comments"? I can't see that in your code anywhere. Btw, that JS snippet is useless without any context.

Comment: It is meant as a guestbook. User can add a comment and the receiving user can reply on that comment. As long as there is no reply there will be an textarea and submit button (This is working fine). If replied than only text. So if a user receives multiple comments there will be mulitple textareas for a reply. Every textarea has a set of smilies attached. Smilies work only if there is 1 comment and 1 unanswered reply. As soon as there are multiple unanswered replies only text input is working.

Comment: you can't have multiple elements with the same ID ("txtreply" in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strstr use str_replace with something like this:

```
$smiles = array(
    ':-)' => '<img ...>',
    ...
);

$comment = str_replace(array_keys($smiles), array_values($smiles), $comment);
```

Aside from this it would be better if you do the replace when you display the comment/reply, rather than when you save it to the database.